# shown SVG bar chart values after animation only using SMIL

Tags: html, svg

I am rendering an SVG along with SMIL animations. In that bar chart SVG, bar values are shown before the actual bars rendering. I want to show bar chart values only after bars are rendered completely. Below is my SVG code.

I have tried to solve for a long period. Please help me solve this.

```html
<svg width="710px" height="231px" viewBox="0 0 710 231">
  <!-- Generator: Sketch 53.2 (72643) - https://sketchapp.com  -->
  <title>Chart_IncreaseInAttacks</title>
  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-increaseinattacks" class="graph-clipath active">
       <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
        d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
        id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero">
         <animateTransform 
          attributeType="XML" 
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate"
          values="-505,0; 0,0" 
          begin="0s"
          calcMode="spline"
          keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
          dur="0.3s" 
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
       <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform = translate(-505,0) width="505"
        d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
        id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero">
         <animateTransform 
          attributeType="XML" 
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate"
          values="-505,0; 0,0" 
          begin="0.3s"
          calcMode="spline"
          keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69" 
          dur="0.3s" 
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
       <path x="150" y="0" height="300" transform= translate(-505,0) width="505"
        d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
        id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero">
         <animateTransform 
          attributeType="XML" 
          attributeName="transform" 
          type="translate"
          values="-505,0; 0,0" 
          begin="0.6s"
          calcMode="spline"
          keySplines= ".4,0,.78,.69"
          dur="0.3s" 
          fill="freeze"/>
      </path>
   </clipPath>
  </defs>
   <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="ATT-CS-Report02_SecurityRiskLandscape" transform="translate(-245.000000, -440.000000)">
    <g id="Chart_IncreaseInAttacks" transform="translate(245.000000, 440.000000)">
    <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-14" fill="#F6F6F6" fill-rule="nonzero" x="0" y="0" width="710" height="231"></rect>
    <text id="Increase-in-attacks" font-size="15" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="22" fill="#009FDB">
    <tspan x="42" y="40">Increase in attacks in 2018</tspan>
    </text>
    <text id="Ransomware-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
    <tspan x="68.462" y="83">Ransomware </tspan>
    <tspan x="96.765" y="97">attacks</tspan>
    </text>
    <text id="Spear-phishing-attac" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
    <tspan x="58.199" y="167">Spear-phishing</tspan>
    <tspan x="96.765" y="181">attacks</tspan>
    </text>
    <text id="Spoofing/BEC-attacks" font-size="11" font-weight="normal" line-spacing="14" fill="#191919">
    <tspan x="83.301" y="125">Spoofing/</tspan>
    <tspan x="74.27" y="139">BEC attacks</tspan>
    </text>
      <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)" id="kk"
    d="M150,75 L643,75 C649.627417,75 655,80.372583 655,87 L655,87 C655,93.627417 649.627417,99 643,99 L150,99 L150,75 Z"
    id="Rectangle-Copy-15" fill="#0F54AF" fill-rule="nonzero"> </path>
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
    d="M150,117 L499,117 C505.627417,117 511,122.372583 511,129 L511,129 C511,135.627417 505.627417,141 499,141 L150,141 L150,117 Z"
    id="Rectangle-Copy-18" fill="#009FDB" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    <path clip-path="url(#clip-path-increaseinattacks)"
     d="M150,159 L239,159 C245.627417,159 251,164.372583 251,171 L251,171 C251,177.627417 245.627417,183 239,183 L150,183 L150,159 Z"
     id="Rectangle-Copy-19" fill="#30D1FF" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>




     <path d="M150.5,68.5 L150.5,190" id="Line-3-Copy" stroke="#191919" stroke-linecap="square" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
     <text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
     <tspan x="159" y="90">350%</tspan>
     </text>
     <text id="250%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
      <tspan x="159" y="132">250%</tspan>
     </text>
     <text id="70%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF">
     <tspan x="159" y="174">70%</tspan>
     </text>
  </g>
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: change their visibility or display property using SMIL.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you provide a sample example. that would be helpful. will implement in our project.

Comment: Could you tell me where you're stuck on implementing it. I'm not going to write all your code for you.

Comment: Do you need to animate the white text? You may `<animate>` the `opacity` from 0 to 1

Comment: Yup @enxaneta.I need exactly that one only. but I need that bar animation and text animation parallely

Comment: @RobertLongson I have did the answer. which is working in chrome but  not working on firefox.
Here is the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4syvnm?file=index.html

Please have a look.

Comment: @enxaneta, can you check my code. where I was mistaken. this code is working fine in chrome but not working in firefox
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4syvnm?file=index.html

Comment: For the text animation you may do this `<text id="350%" font-size="12" font-weight="bold" line-spacing="16" fill="#FFFFFF" opacity="0">
     <tspan x="159" y="90" >350%</tspan>
        <animate 
          attributeType="XML" 
          attributeName="opacity" 
          from="0" to="1" 
          begin="0.1s"
          dur="0.3s" 
          fill="freeze"/>
     </text>`

Comment: The  stackblitz code is working for me in FF

Comment: In that example, bar values are rendered before animation. Please have a look again

Comment: @enxaneta, in chrome it is rendered after animation. But in FF not working like that